# How to left-align a matrix inside the table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, matrices

I have a table that contains two matrices. I want to left-align these matrices, instead of center align. I am using IEEE format. In addition, the bracket `[]`of matrix is very close to the `\hline` of the table. Could we have any way to make a margin between the bracket and the hline?

```
\begin{table*}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{This is table}
\label{table_network_architecture}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
\bfseries Name & \bfseries Matrix  \\
\hline\hline
%Dense 2
Text 1 & $\left[ \begin{array}{c} 30 \times 30 \\ 30 \times 30 \end{array}\right]$\\
\hline
Text 1 & $\left[ \begin{array}{c} 30 \times 30 \\ 30 \times 30 \end{array}\right]-100$\\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}   
\end{table*}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd prefer the `booktabs` way shown by gernot, but if you insist in ruling your table, you can use `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{This is table}
\label{table_network_architecture}
\medskip

\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells

\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries Name} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries Matrix} \\
\hline
Text 1 & $\begin{bmatrix} 30 \times 30 \\ 30 \times 30 \end{bmatrix}$ \\
\hline
Text 2, longer & $\begin{bmatrix} 30 \times 30 \\ 30 \times 30 \end{bmatrix}-100$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To left-align the elements in a column, use `l` instead of `c` as column specifier.

The problem with the extra space cannot be solved simply by increasing `\arraystretch`, because it affects the table in the same way as the arrays. One can reset the `\arraystretch` to 1 immediately before the arrays, but this still gives no nice spacing. One way to solve it is to use the `booktabs` package.

Final remark: Instead of `\left[\begin{array}{c} ... \end{array}\right]` you can use `\begin{bmatrix} ... \end{bmatrix}`; `bmatrix` is defined in the package `amsmath`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cl}
\toprule
\bfseries Name & \bfseries Matrix  \\
\midrule
Text 1 & 
$\begin{bmatrix} 30 \times 30 \\ 30 \times 30 \end{bmatrix}$\\
\midrule
Text 1 &
$\begin{bmatrix} 30 \times 30 \\ 30 \times 30 \end{bmatrix}-100$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: But \midrule make my \vline is not continuous.

Comment: @user8264 Many people, in particular those in professional typesetting, consider vertical lines as redundant, even as confusing rather than supporting. The `booktabs` package operates under the assumption that you don't use vertical lines.

Answer (score 3):

One can add a 2pt (`\fboxsep`} gap on all sides using `\fbox` with `\fboxrule=0pt`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}
\caption{This is table}
\label{table_network_architecture}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|l}
\hline
\bfseries Name & \bfseries Matrix  \\
\hline\hline
%Dense 2
Text 1 & \fbox{$\left[ \begin{array}{c} 30 \times 30 \\ 30 \times 30 \end{array}\right]$}\\
\hline
Text 1 & \fbox{$\left[ \begin{array}{c} 30 \times 30 \\ 30 \times 30 \end{array}\right]-100$}\\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}   
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

Alternatively, one can add appropriate struts for extra large text using

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\arraybox}[1]% #1 = extra large text
{\bgroup
  \sbox0{#1}% measure
  \rule{0pt}{\arraystretch\ht0}% top strut
  \rule[-\arraystretch\dp0]{0pt}{0pt}% bottom strut
  \box0
\egroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{This is table}
\label{table_network_architecture}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|l}
\hline
\bfseries Name & \bfseries Matrix  \\
\hline\hline
%Dense 2
Text 1 & \arraybox{$\left[ \begin{array}{c} 30 \times 30 \\ 30 \times 30 \end{array}\right]$}\\
\hline
Text 1 & \arraybox{$\left[ \begin{array}{c} 30 \times 30 \\ 30 \times 30 \end{array}\right]-100$}\\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}   
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo 2]